How to add map marker cluster that can responsive with 3d model map that i created?
I create flutter project to display university map with 3d object
My map screen
But i want to make mapmarker to the 3d object that can responsive when it's zoom in or zoom out
it's possible to do it? and what lib i can use? thank you
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:model_viewer_plus/model_viewer_plus.dart';

class layermap extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Map Layer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        minScale: 12.0,
        maxScale: 20.0,
        child: ModelViewer(
          src: 'assets/maptest.glb',
          alt: "SRINAKARINWIROT UNIVERSITY",
          cameraControls: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, '');
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

// add mapmarker to 3 d model map 




enter image description here
That is the result i want (in expectation)
